# JFrame with common behaviour - composition or inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, jframe, composition

I have three similar classes responsible for displaying swing frame with various components. They all are composed with JFrame and contain  the same duplicating setRandomLocation() method. In order to get rid of it, what should I do?

1. Stay with preferred-by-everyone composition and create some Util class with getRandomLocation(),
2. Create something like RandomLocatedFrame extending JFrame, and then use this class as a base for my classes - but is such added behaviour enough to justify using inheritance?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If `getRandomLocation` is a real verb of your classes (like `setVisible` or `dispose`), you should use inheritance as you described. If the method just generates random coordinates to put the frame, it should be in another class, not in a frame.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you well, but if I left this method inside the class, it would be setRandomLocation just like setVisible etc., it would count the location and then set it, and return no value. On the other hand, if I moved it to some Utils, then it would be getRandomLocation and would just cound and return the coordinates to calling JFrame object, which then would set the location.

Comment: Make a parent class with `setRandomLocation` and inherit it in three classes. OR: use `Factory` pattern to create frames. It will create,setRandomLocation and track locations used to not place a frame on another.